# Subtract the value of a row from grouped result

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a table supplier_account which has five coloumns supplier_account_id(pk),supplier_id(fk),voucher_no,debit and credit. I want to get the sum of debit grouped by supplier_id and then subtract the value of credit of the rows in which voucher_no is not null. So for each subsequent rows the value of sum of debit gets reduced. I have tried using 'with' clause.

```
with debitdetails as(
select supplier_id,sum(debit) as amt
from supplier_account group by supplier_id
)
select acs.supplier_id,s.supplier_name,acs.purchase_voucher_no,acs.purchase_voucher_date,dd.amt-acs.credit as amount
from supplier_account acs
left join supplier s on acs.supplier_id=s.supplier_id
left join debitdetails dd on acs.supplier_id=dd.supplier_id
where voucher_no is not null
```

But here the debit value will be same for all rows. After subtraction in the first row I want to get the result in second row and subtract the next credit value from that.

I know it is possible by using temporary tables. The problem is I cannot use temporary tables because the procedure is used to generate reports using Jasper Reports.

Comment: You use the terms "subsequent rows" and "first row" and "second row" and "next" but there is no ordering of your data so how can any particular row be "first" or "second" or "next"? If you want to accumulate amounts you will have to explain better how exactly that is meant to work. Perhaps some sample data and sample expected output would help someone to give you an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is an implementation of the running total. The easiest way to do it with a help of a window function:

```
with debitdetails as(
select id,sum(debit) as amt
from suppliers group by id
)
select s.id, purchase_voucher_no, dd.amt, s.credit,
dd.amt - sum(s.credit) over (partition by s.id order by purchase_voucher_no asc)
from suppliers s
left join debitdetails dd on s.id=dd.id
order by s.id, purchase_voucher_no
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2bfc1/7)

Results:

```
| id | purchase_voucher_no | amt | credit | ?column? |
|----|---------------------|-----|--------|----------|
|  1 |                   1 |  43 |      5 |       38 |
|  1 |                   2 |  43 |     18 |       20 |
|  1 |                   3 |  43 |      8 |       12 |
|  2 |                   4 |  60 |      5 |       55 |
|  2 |                   5 |  60 |     15 |       40 |
|  2 |                   6 |  60 |     30 |       10 |
```